# RMarkdown Octave Plot

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Can RMarkdown produce plots when using Octave for its engine?  Here's a basic example:

````
```{octave}
plot([1,2,3])
```
````

In CoCalc, as in Octave and MATLAB, the output would be a plot.  Similarly, when using the R engine in RMarkdown for

````
```{r}
plot(c(1,2,3))
```
````

I would like to be able to do this for Octave in RMarkdown - is there a solution for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the `engine`? Or have you coded this and attempted to run the chunk? Octave isn't one of the built-in languages (pretty sure, not 100% on that), so you have to tell the script where to look for the compiler for Octave. Additionally, running the chunk won't do anything, you'll have to knit to see the output. The only language that by default works without knitting is R. You can expand that to using both Python and R with reticulate. With knitting, the language options are endless.

Comment: Thanks Kat, I really enjoy the knitting capabilities of RMarkdown using RStudio.  I have coded this and my Octave chunks run when I knit the document, but the plots are not generated.  Octave is one of the supported engines in RMarkdown with knitr, along with Python and others (besides R); see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html.   I have the path set correctly for the octave engine and can run other basic Octave commands and scripts successfully in RMarkdown when I knit the file, just not the ones that produce a plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave's function plot does not return an image, but opens a window instead. This is why it also doesn't work on R Studio Server by default. Here is a workaround by using `print()` and displaying the image afterwards:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE,
  engine.path = list(
    octave = "/usr/bin/octave"
  )
)
```

```{octave}
plot([1,2,3])

print("file.png")
```

![](file.png)
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this answers my question and the workaround is successful for me.  This also explains why I would still get compiler feedback on the plot, like "## warning: legend: 'best' not yet implemented for location specifier, using 'northeast' instead".